# How to cite something which is cited another book

Tags: biblatex

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents*}{reference.bib}
@Book{Houghton1995,
  Title                    = {The Search for God: Can Science Help?},
  Author                   = {John Houghton},
  Publisher                = {Lion Books},
  Year                     = {1995},
  Address                  = {Oxford}
}

@Book{Lennox2009,
  Title                    = {God's Undertaker: Has Science Buried God?},
  Author                   = {John C. Lennox},
  Publisher                = {Lion Books},
  Year                     = {2009},
  Note                     = {Originally published in 2007.}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{reference.bib}

\title{My Doc}
\author{Me}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

Our science is God's science. He holds the responsibility for the whole scientific story.\dots The remarkable order, consistency, reliability and fascinating complexity found in the scientific description of the universe are reflections of the order, consistency, reliability and complexity of God's activity.

\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

The quote above is from `Lennox2009`, and that source quoted it from `Houghton1995`. I do not have access to the original source. Is there methodical way to make such a citation?

Comment: You may be interested in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27964/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63484/35864. If this is just a one-off, a manual solution like `\mkbibparens{\cite{Houghton1995} as quoted in \cite{Lennox2009}}` (untested, but something like this should work) might be easier than building up a big machinery to deal with these sort of things more elegantly.

Comment: Did the linked question help you or are you still looking for an answer? If the latter is the case, please consider editing your question to explain why the linked questions are not what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, it helped. Thank you.